# Prove that $1982\cdot 1983|\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{1980}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $1982\cdot 1983|\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{1980}$

Since $\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{1980}=\frac{2(10^{1980}-1)}{10-1}$ then I need to show that $9\cdot 1982\cdot 1983| 2(10^{1980}-1)$, or $9\cdot 991\cdot 1983|(10^{1980}-1)$ since $(9,991,1983)=1$ if I show that  $9|(10^{1980}-1)$,  $991|(10^{1980}-1)$,  $1983|(10^{1980}-1)$  then I finish the task.

Since $10\equiv 1 (mod{9})$ then $10^{1980}\equiv 1(mod{9})$ so $10^{1980}-1\equiv 0 (mod{9})$ so we show that $9|(10^{1980}-1)$.

In $991|(10^{1980}-1)$ we can use Euler's function since $(991,10)=1$ so $10^{\varphi (991)}\equiv 1 (mod 991)$ so $10^{990}\equiv 1 (mod{9})$ then if I square $10^{2\cdot 990}\equiv 1 (mod{991})$ so $10^{1980}-1\equiv 0 (mod{991})$.

Then  $1983|(10^{1980}-1)$ $1983=3\cdot 661$ $3|10^{1980}-1$ it is trivial, and we can you Euler's theorem then $10^{660}\equiv 1(mod{661})$ and then $10^{3\cdot 660}\equiv 1 (mod{661})$ so $10^{1980}-1\equiv 0 (mod{661})$.

But I just not so sure when you show something like this and number $x,y,z \in \mathbb N$ (x,y,z)=1 and if say (y,x)=3 then that not change anything in task, if we want to show that x|n y|n and z|n? If you understand what I ask, here $(9,1983)=3$, but $(9,1982,1983)=1$

Comment: You need a backslash before "underbrace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $\gcd(9,1982,1983)=1$, you have $\gcd(9,1983)\ne 1$. You should rather factor
$ 9\cdot 1982\cdot 1983$ as $27\cdot 661\cdot 991$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1982\cdot 1983|\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{1980}$$
$$2\cdot991\cdot 1983|\underbrace{\left(11 \ldots1\right)}_{1980}\cdot2$$

This implies that $\gcd \geq 2$ and therefore it is $1982\cdot 1983|\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{1980}$